# Trying to save attached msg file in local disk in java

Tags: java, email

I am reading outlook msg file in java using msgparser. Below code.

```
MsgParser msgp = new MsgParser();
Message msg = msgp.parseMsg("temp.msg");            
List<Attachment> atts = msg.getAttachments();

for (Attachment att : atts) {
    if (att instanceof FileAttachment) {

    }
    if (att instanceof MsgAttachment){
        MsgAttachment msg1 = (MsgAttachment) att;
        Message msg2 = msg1.getMessage();
    }
}
```

In the above code I got msgAttachment object. I am unable to write that into a file. I want that to be written as a outlook msg file.

Comment: I have this problem to. Will update if I find a solution.

Comment: Did you find a solution to save it?

Answer (score -1):

I see you are using Java. You can try using jacob framework.
Prerequisites for using Jacob framework is to load jacob dll library.

In order to read mail and other mail properties you can go through the link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa210946(v=office.11).aspx

Assumption made--You are trying to read the mail through Outlook Client.

To store attachments from the mail you can try using below code.

```
ActiveXComponent xl = new ActiveXComponent(
                    "Outlook.Application");
Dispatch explorer = Dispatch
                    .get(xl, "ActiveExplorer").toDispatch();
Dispatch selection = Dispatch.get(explorer,
                    "Selection").toDispatch();
Variant count = Dispatch.get(selection, "Count");
int toInt = count.getInt();
for(int j=1;i<=toInt;i++){
    Dispatch mailItem = Dispatch.call(selection,
          "Item", new Variant(j)).toDispatch();
    Dispatch attachs = Dispatch.get(mailItem, "Attachments").toDispatch();

    Variant count1 = Dispatch.get(attachs, "Count");
    int numberOfAttach = count1.getInt();           
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfAttach; i++) {

        Attachment attach = new Attachment();
        Dispatch attachment = Dispatch.call(attachs, "Item",
                new Variant(i)).toDispatch();

        //get the name of the file 
        Variant nameOfFile = Dispatch.get(attachment, "DisplayName");                       
        String displayName = nameOfFile.getString();
        Variant type = Dispatch.get(attachment, "Type");

        Variant saveAttachment = null;
        saveAttachment = Dispatch.call(attachment, "SaveAsFile","path where attachment need to be saved");
    }
}
```